# How can I make OxyPlot adjust zoom when calling PlotView.Invalidate?

Tags: oxyplot

I have a problem with OxyPlot which is as follows:

I create a new PlotView and attach a PlotModel with some axes when my program starts.

In my program, the user can open a file, which is interpreted and plotted in the PlotView control.

To display the new Series, I do

```
myPlotView.Invalidate(true);
```

This will display the data on in the plot, however OxyPlot does not perform any zooming. How can I pan and zoom automatically, such that the plot covers the whole PlotView?

I tried to set

```
 myPlotView.Model.Axes[0].DataMinimum = someValue1
    myPlotView.Model.Axes[1].DataMinimum = someValue2
    myPlotView.Model.Axes[0].DataMaximum = someValue3
    myPlotView.Model.Axes[1].DataMaximum = someValue4
```

but nothing happens.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Axes calculates the `ViewMinimum` and `ViewMaxium` (the real thing you are watching) only if Minimum and Maximum are not specified, you can set them to `Double.NaN` before resetting, so the ViewMinimum and ViewMaximum will be calculated based on `DataMinimum` and `DataMaximum`

```
foreach (var ax in _plotModel.Axes)
    ax.Maximum = ax.Minimum = Double.NaN;
PlotView.ResetAllAxes();
```

Also if you changed the data points, you must call to `Plot.InvalidatePlot()` so the `DataMinimum` and `DataMaximum` gets updated too.

Answer (score 1):

Do a Axis reset and update the Minimum/Maximum of each Axis.

e.g.

```
      PlotView.ActualModel.Axes[0].Reset();
      PlotView.ActualModel.Axes[1].Reset();

      PlotView.ActualModel.Axes[0].Minimum = 50;
      PlotView.ActualModel.Axes[0].Maximum = 250;

      PlotView.ActualModel.Axes[1].Minimum = 50;
      PlotView.ActualModel.Axes[1].Maximum = 250;
      PlotView.InvalidatePlot(true);
```

you should of course use the min/max value from your data.

Comment: I ended up creating a new PlotModel with my data since this required less code. I mark this as accepted, but I have a feeling that it must be an easier way. PlotView.Refresh() does not work either?